# checking how many external storages are mounted

Tags: java, android, java-io

How to check how many external storage are mounted in android. 
i.e. External SD card or USB storage and get file path for them.

For external storage there is `root/mnt/sdcard` but is this path works for every device?

Note: I tried with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` but it returns only primary external storage. I want externally mounted storage path.

Comment: Have a look at getExternalFilesDirs(). You might be lucky. Use StorageVolumes on Android 7+.

Comment: `For external storage there is root/mnt/sdcard`. No never. But often its on `/mnt/sdcard`.